# while loop nested in a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I was using a nested while loop, and ran into a problem, as the inner loop is only run once.
To demonstrate I've made a bit of test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while(i < 10){
    printf("i:%d\n", i);
    while(j < 10){
      printf("j:%d\n", j);
      j++;
    }
  i++;
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
i:0
j:0
j:1
j:2
j:3
j:4
j:5
j:6
j:7
j:8
j:9
i:1
i:2
i:3
i:4
i:5
i:6
i:7
i:8
i:9
```

Can anyone explain why the nested loop doesn't execute 10 times? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Use two for() loops ?

Comment: use for loops instead!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You never reset the value of `j` to `0`, and as such, your inner loop condition is never true after the first run. Assigning `j = 0;` in the outer loop afterward should fix it.

Comment: Oh wow. I feel stupid right now. Ah well, not like it's the first time :p Thanks!

Comment: Never? Never again ... !-)

Comment: Actually, never. I set it once, but never _reset_ it.

Answer (score 4):

Because you don't reset it in each iteration of the outer loop. If you want the inner loop to run ten times too, put the initialization of the `j` variable inside the outer loop, like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    printf("i:%d\n", i);
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 10) {
        printf("j:%d\n", j);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-set the value `j` to `0` after the inner loop is done.

Answer (score 1):

`j`  needs to be initialized to 0 inside the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while(i < 10){
    printf("i:%d\n", i);
    j = 0 ; // initialization
    while(j < 10){
      printf("j:%d\n", j);
      j++;
    }
  i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: 5 year late nitpick: the commented line is an assignment, not initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset j to 0. You don't ever do that in your code  Make j equal to 0 in your outside loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your inner loop only executes once is because you initialize j to 0 outside the loop and then never reset it again. After it runs the first time the value of j is 10. It will never be less than 10 again.

A better way to do this is to use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("i:%i\n", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("j:%i\n", j);
    }
}
```

It also makes the code look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You never reset the value of j to 0, and as such, your inner loop condition is never true after the first run. Assigning j = 0; in the outer loop afterward should fix it.